# How to prove the Big-Oh for the following statements?

Tags: functions, asymptotics

I have learned to prove Big-Oh for statements containing only polynomial functions. But I am having a hard time solving the following ones because they happen to have many types of function in one statement, like logarithmic and polynomial and exponential in the same statement. I have approached in the way which I use to proof for polynomial times, but with this statements, appraoching in that style is not giving any result. Here are the problems
Sorry for poor formatting of the equations.

1. $1000n^2 + 16n + 2^n$
2. $n\log(n) + 15n + 0.002n^2$
3. $37n + n\log(n^2) + 5000\log(n)$

I know the answer of them to be $O(2^n)$, $O(n^2)$, $O(n\log(n^2))$. But I think I have not been able to prove them in a formal way.

What I have done so far is, As I have to prove $f(n) \leq cg(n)$, for $n \geq k$, I take some arbitrary values of $k$, like set $k$ to $1$, and try to find the value of $c$ from the equation. What I want to know, how to formally prove this?

Comment: You can evaluate the limits of the given expressions over the big-O functions and check that they are finite.

Comment: Can you describe more? Or show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a scale of comparison, which here will be made up of functions of type:
$$\log^\alpha\! n \:n^\beta\, 2^{\gamma n}.$$
Now these functions are totally ordered, by the relation $f=o(g)$, that we'll denote $\: f\prec g$.

This order is identical to the lexicographic order on the triplets $(\alpha,\beta, \gamma)$, so that
$$\log n\prec n\prec n\log n \prec n^2 \prec 2^n$$
and

1. $f(n)=1000n^2 + 16n + 2^n=2^n+o\bigl(2^n\bigr)\sim_\infty 2^n$, so  $\color{red}{f(n)=O\bigl(2^n\bigr)}$.
2. $g(n)=nlog(n) + 15n + 0.002n^2= 0.002n^2+o(n^2)\sim_\infty 0.002n^2 $, so $\color{red}{g(n)=O(n^2)}$.
3. $h(n)=37n + nlog(n^2) + 5000log(n)=2n\log n+o(n\log n)\sim_\infty 2n\log n$, so $\color{red}{h(n)=O(n\log n)}$.